# OpenGL: How to scale and keep its location(X, Y) where it was before

Tags: c++, opengl

I don't know the right term to describe it that is why I can't find it in Google. All I want is to scale the object, specifically, 2D rectangle but keep it on its XY coordinates.

My current solution is this:

```
glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
glScalef(scaleX, scaleY, 0);
glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0);
drawRect(x, y, width, height, texture);
```

I just pretend glScale as glRotate as of rotating on its center, it somewhat work but I can see the little adjustments on its coordinate when scaling to other value.

And also, which is better to do, glTranslate or just apply variables such as x,y on vertices. I can't see no difference when switching from those two but I am worrying about adding the "pushing and popping matrices" will affect the behavior of other objects on the scene and performance of my program, because I will use lots of this rectangles.

**Update:**

So you can visualize how simply I want to achieve

[image: adobe photoshop at its best]

Comment: Great question! I've been wondering about this concept myself for a long time. It seems in the OpenGL/DirectX world, if you're not a math major and you aren't married to matrices you're forced to be a script kiddie with things like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that <`x`,`y`,`0`> is the position of the bottom left corner of your rectangle in the "canonical" coordinate system (I mean the one we start with).

With these assumptions, you may achieve your goal by resetting the modelview stack to identity, and then move to the object space, before doing the scaling. So you are indeed pretty close, but depending on what you did before with the modelview matrix, you could experience variations in the outcome.

The following code should do what you want:

```
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
// now in "object space"
glScalef(scaleX, scaleY, 0);
drawRect(0, 0, width, height, texture);
glPopMatrix();
```

I don't know what the `draw` function does, but I suppose that it just emits a bunch of `glVertex` and `glTexCoord` calls, ie. it does not meddle with the modelview matrix, otherwise my code might well break it.

Note that if you wrap all object rendering with `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` calls, you should not need the `glLoadIdentity` call, and it might even be counter productive. For instance, if you organize your object data as a hierarchy, with each sub object being relatively positioned to its container, then you will need to remove that call completely while recursively rendering the object hierarchy.

Another concern is the one of efficiency. Saving and restoring matrices are fairly costly operations. Given that your question code is using immediate mode, I supposed that it was not your main concern. It will certainly be faster to apply the object transformation by hand (that is, by computing them with your own matrix library), and submit them to opengl without any call to the opengl modelview manipulation routines. However That should be covered by another (more math oriented) question and answer.

Comment: yes you are right, `drawRect` just calls `glDrawers` and nothing else. But, what if I remove the (X,Y) in `drawRect` and just `glTranslate` because it just does nothing since you said it can be zero?

Comment: I haven't try it yet because I'm not in my PC but will this also work if the origin is top-left of the rectangle as well as the window?

Comment: The code I gave will scale relatively to the `x` and `y` coordinates (ie. <x,y,0> will be the scaling centre point). If by window coordinate you mean the pixel coordinate of the final image, then you should not be worried about it. If you mean that your global space coordinate is mirrored on the Y axis, then you will probably need to include that step again after the `glLoadIdentity` call. Actually, let me add something to my answer.

Comment: Many thanks! I remove the x,y variables(that is why it don't works the first time I try your code) and leave the translation to glTranslate.

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for a rotation by angle `phi` (applies to other affine transformations as well) that keeps the point `(x,y)` fixed is

```
TRANSLATE(-x, -y)
ROTATE(phi)
TRANSLATE(x, y)
```

Transformations are applied in order from top to bottom. So you're moving the point `(x,y)` into the origin at `(0,0)`. It will thus not be affected by the actual rotation. When you're done, the second translation reverses the effect of the first.

This is not limited to OpenGL, but rather applies to any type of graphics processing that supports affine transformations (through matrices or quaternions).

Comment: How to do that using scaling?

Comment: yes, that's the general pattern to apply any transformation relatively to a certain point in space (other than the origin).